# Task.Wait() deadlocks my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, azure

I have read that it is beneficial to use async/await on networking, so I want to apply it to uploading a file to azure blobs.

When I use `.Wait()` on the method, the application stalls on `await _Container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();`. I want to use `.Wait()` because the `InitializeCategories(context)` method needs to wait for the blobs to be uploaded before it can loop through them.

I'm completely new to using multi-threading, can someone explain why this is happening and tell me how to fix it?

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    base.Seed(context);

    InitializeImages().Wait();
    InitializeCategories(context);
}

public static async Task InitializeImages()
{
    _PlaceHolderImage = "placeholder-categories.jpg";
    _StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    _BlobClient = _StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    _Container = _BlobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

    await _Container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    //To view the blob in the browser
    await _Container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _Container.GetBlockBlobReference(_PlaceHolderImage);
    await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + _PlaceHolderImage), FileMode.Open);
}

public static void InitializeCategories(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    // Loop over items within the container and output the length and URI.
    foreach (IListBlobItem item in _Container.ListBlobs())
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

            Console.WriteLine("Block blob of length {0}: {1}", blob.Properties.Length, blob.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the signature of "protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)" to protected override async Task Seed(ApplicationDbContext)? Then you can await InitializeImages() and remove the Wait() call.

Comment: @Jeroen The signatures wouldn't match if I did change that. The base method is in an external library so I can't change that.

Comment: Try changing this line `await _Container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();` to `await _Container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: @YacoubMassad It gets to this line now `await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync` and throws a null reference exception on `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: How often does this code run? Does it run on each ASP.NET request?

Comment: Do not use async if you cannot do it all the way. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) article for more background information.

Comment: @YacoubMassad It runs on startup of the app.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson, then there is probably not a good reason to make it asynchronous

Comment: can you try ```     await Task.Run(()>{
        _Container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
    });```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have read that it is beneficial to use async/await on networking

Yes, but *why*?

The answer is: `async` is beneficial (especially for I/O-based code) so that you free up threads to do other things. In an ASP.NET app, this means you have more threads available to handle incoming requests. Oh, wait...

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
```

When your application is handling its first request (and seeding the db), there isn't any point in freeing up threads because they won't be able to do anything until after the db is seeded anyway.

So in this situation, you should just synchronously upload.

> can someone explain why this is happening

I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that goes into more detail, but to summarize:

- `await` by default will capture a "context", and will resume executing the `async` method in that context.
- ASP.NET (currently) has a request context that handles things like `HttpContext.Current`, the current page culture, etc.
- The ASP.NET context only allows one thread in at a time.

Thus, when you block a thread in the request context (`Wait`), the `async` method cannot complete because it's waiting for that request context to be free. Of course, the `Wait` is waiting for the `async` method to complete, so you end up with a deadlock.

Comment: Your blog post was great and helped a lot. What do you mean when referring to 'context' though?

Comment: The context is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case the context is `TaskScheduler.Current`. In this case, it is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, which is an instance of `AspNetSynchronizationContext`.